# JDBC MySQL complains Too Many Connections

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat7

When this happens, i check in my db(refer to table below), the connections has not reach the limit of 1000. This is weird... wonder if there's a hidden hard limit being hit.

```
mysql> show variables like 'max_connections';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 1000  |
+-----------------+-------+

mysql> SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Max_used_connections';
+----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name        | Value |
+----------------------+-------+
| Max_used_connections | 510   |
+----------------------+-------+
```

FYI, my application is having an average of 300 connections to the database. So any idea? Thanks.

My setup: tomcat7, spring 3.1, tomcat7-dbcp, mysql5.5, java7

Comment: Is it possible that some of your connections are not correctly closed?

Comment: oh, does that matter? I didn't look into that part yet, as it's not reaching the limit of the connections.

Comment: I am not entirely certain in your case, but I ran into a similar issue that was traced down to unclosed, orphaned connections.

Comment: mmmm well, i guess that's a good insight for me :) let me dig this out will update here again for any finding, thanks mate!

Comment: Just .close() your Java.sql.Connection. The Connection will get released automatically eventually but this way you will be sure to relase the ressource immeadiatly.

Comment: Btw: You can look at all connections to your database by query-ing SHOW PROCESSLIST; Certain Connections can get closed by KILL <pid>;

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is that the MySQL server is hitting a limit on the number of open file descriptors imposed by the host OS.

For example, this blog posting describes a problem on Debian:

- https://codepoets.co.uk/2015/mysql-max_connections-stuck-on-214/

Here is a Q&A that talks about the same thing:

- [The max_connections in MySQL 5.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39976756/the-max-connections-in-mysql-5-7)