# The max_connections in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, max, connection

I met a problem, the value of max_connction in MySQL is 214 after I set it 1000 via edit the my.cnf, just like below:

```
hadoop@node1:~$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.15, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

MySQL version: 5.7

OS version   :   ubuntu 16.04LTS

```
mysql> show variables like 'max_connections';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 151   |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As we can see, the variable value of max_connections is 151. Then , I edit the configuration file of MySQL.

```
yang2@node1:~$ sudo vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
[mysqld]

character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
max_connections=1000
```

Restart MySQL service after save the configraion.

```
yang2@node1:~$ service mysql restart
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to restart 'mysql.service'.
Multiple identities can be used for authentication:
 1.  yangqiang,,, (yang2)
 2.  ,,, (hadoop)
Choose identity to authenticate as (1-2): 1
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
yang2@node1:~$
```

Now, we guess the max_connection is 1000, really?

```
mysql> show variables like 'max_connections';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 214   |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It is 214. I do not really understand this result, who can help me? thx!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As MySQL documentation on [max_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) setting says:

> Increasing this value increases the number of file descriptors that
>   mysqld requires. If the required number of descriptors are not
>   available, the server reduces the value of max_connections.

This means that probably your MySQL server does not have enough resources to maintain the required number of descriptors.

MySQL documentation on [How MySQL Opens and Closes Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-cache.html) makes it clear that:

> The table_open_cache and max_connections system variables affect the
>   maximum number of files the server keeps open. If you increase one or
>   both of these values, you may run up against a limit imposed by your
>   operating system on the per-process number of open file descriptors.
>   Many operating systems permit you to increase the open-files limit,
>   although the method varies widely from system to system. Consult your
>   operating system documentation to determine whether it is possible to
>   increase the limit and how to do so.

Comment: Thank you so much, and can you tell me the detail resources that MySQL server required, My computer has 16GB memory and 8 cores. So I don't know what is the "enough resources" .

Comment: The resource is the max number of file descriptors controlled by the OS, not your memory and processor capacity.

Comment: I just want to update the number of file descriptions, but I can get the value of the file description now , it is  1024 in my OS, is it too small ?thanks again!

Comment: The documentation on How MySQL Opens and Closes Tables (linked in the answer) explains how to estimate the number of file descriptors required for your operation. 1024 is a way too low, if you want support 1000 concurrent connections.

Answer (score 15):

You may set the value manually, e.g.

```
set global max_connections=500;
```

however, after a restart of MySQL the value is reset to 214.

The solution depends on the (version of) OS and the MySQL version. With Ubuntu 16.04 and MySQL >= 5.7.7 following works:

systemctl edit mysql

Enter

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=8000
```

save, this will create a new file

/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf

and restart the server:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart mysql
```

For other environments:  [Can not increase max_open_files for Mysql max-connections in Ubuntu 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901041/can-not-increase-max-open-files-for-mysql-max-connections-in-ubuntu-15)

Answer (score 5):

Follow the following steps:

```
cp /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service /etc/systemd/system/
echo -e "\r\nLimitNOFILE=infinity" >> /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service
echo "LimitMEMLOCK=infinity" >> /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo service mysql restart
```

And change or add he following line into file **/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf** :

```
[mysqld]
max_connections=110
```

Just this!
@Mahdi_Mohammadi

Answer (score 3):

1.Edit mysql service file

```
#sudo cat /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service
# MySQL systemd service file

[Unit]
Description=MySQL Community Server
After=network.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=mysql
Group=mysql
PIDFile=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
TimeoutSec=600
Restart=on-failure
RuntimeDirectory=mysqld
RuntimeDirectoryMode=755
##this bellow for tuneup 
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
```

2.edit /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
max_connections        = 99999

Answer (score 2):

Add `session required pam_limits.so` in `/etc/pam.d/common-session` (usually is not present by default).

The in `/etc/security/limits.conf` you can add some limits:

```
*   hard    nofile  8192
*   soft    nofile  4096
```

Also check using `ulimit -a` the open files limit.
This you can increase with `ulimit -n 4096`

Make sure you reboot at the end.